# Anonymous block box vs block element

Tags: css, html, specifications

Is it a good way to use anonymous block box instead block element? What are pros and cons?

```
<div>
    Some text
    <p>More text</p>
</div>
```

vs

```
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
</div>
```

P.S. The question arose after reading this point http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level.

Answer (score 2):

You should use semantic markup, meaning using HTML tags that describe your content properly. Look to the CSS specs themselves, which say:

> *CSS gives so much power to the "class" attribute, that authors could conceivably design their own "document language" based on elements with almost no associated presentation (such as DIV and SPAN in HTML) and assigning style information through the "class" attribute. Authors should avoid this practice since the structural elements of a document language often have recognized and accepted meanings and author-defined classes may not.*

I discuss this more on this article: http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticmarkup

In your specific case, if you use CSS to do something like `p:first-line { text-indent:2em }` it will not apply to your "some text" if you do not include the wrapper element. If you include the `<p>` then all styling that applies to paragraphs will properly appear.

<sub>(And you may wish to use a more appropriate element than `<div>`, such as `<section>` if applicable.)</sub>